# ReactJS - Ant-Design v4 jalali(persian) datepicker problem

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, farsi, jalali-calendar

I try a lot to change locale in antd datepicker but I still couldn't. in antd v3 I change locale to persian and have jalali(شمسی) calendar, but in antd v4, I do some ways but only have uncomplete translating.

برای مثال، وقتی دیت‌پیکر فارسی می‌شد، تاریخی که توی دیت‌پیکر قرار می‌گرفت تاریخِ میلادی بود: `۲۰۲۰/۱۰/۰۶`

تنها تغییر این بود که نامِ ماه‌ها به شمسی شده بود. مثلِ «مهر ۲۰۲۰». و روزهای تقویم هم، روزهای شمسی بود، اما وقتی مثلا روی روزِ ۱۵ کلیک می‌کردم، این تاریخ توی دیت‌پیکر انتخاب می‌شد:
۲۰۲۰-۱۰-۰۶

codes:

```
import { DatePicker, ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import "moment/locale/fa";
import moment from "moment";
import fa_IR from "antd/es/locale/fa_IR";
import locale from "antd/es/date-picker/locale/fa_IR";

<ConfigProvider locale={fa_IR}>
    <DatePicker locale={locale} defaultValue={moment()} />
</ConfigProvider>
```

and I also use [ant-design-jalali](https://github.com/vahidalizad/ant-design-jalali). define an alias in webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    alias: {
      moment: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/antd-jalali-moment') // -> this alias
    }
  },
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem this worked for me:

first add [antd-jalali](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-jalali) next add [day jalali js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs-jalali)
after that insert this lines into your code:

```
import 'moment/locale/fa';
import locale from 'antd/es/date-picker/locale/fa_IR';
```

and use in `<DatePickerJalali {...props} locale={locale} />`

Comment: I will try this soon... Mamnoon.

Comment: Its not ant design date picker, Have you tried on that? it dose not work for me

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani No still I didn't try that. I will try today!

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani It importing DatePicket from "antd-jalali" package; but "and-jalali" import datepicker from "antd". and It WORKs!
Thank a lot Mehdi

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DatePicker, ConfigProvider } from 'antd'; 
import "moment/locale/fa"; 
import moment from "moment"; 
import fa_IR from "antd/es/locale/fa_IR"; 
import locale from "antd/es/date-picker/locale/fa_IR"; 

<ConfigProvider locale={fa_IR}> <DatePicker locale={locale} defaultValue={moment()} /> </ConfigProvider>
```